# When i run my android UIAutomator code, it shows error

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-testing

When I run my android UIAutomator code, it shows following error.

> INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.RuntimeException
>   INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=com.android.ui.testing
>   INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0

I just ran the sample code given in developer.android.com
How to solve this error?

Log attached below:

```
01-05 01:07:53.559: D/AndroidRuntime(5712): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
01-05 01:07:53.559: D/AndroidRuntime(5712): CheckJNI is ON
01-05 01:07:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(5712): cannot open customer xml file
01-05 01:07:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(5712): /system/csc/customer.xml can't open file
01-05 01:07:53.564: D/AndroidRuntime(5712): readGMSProperty: start
01-05 01:07:53.564: D/AndroidRuntime(5712): readGMSProperty: already setted!!
01-05 01:07:53.564: D/AndroidRuntime(5712): readGMSProperty: end
01-05 01:07:53.589: D/dalvikvm(5712): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
01-05 01:07:53.599: D/dalvikvm(5712): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
01-05 01:07:53.609: D/dalvikvm(5712): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
01-05 01:07:53.609: D/dalvikvm(5712): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
01-05 01:07:53.664: I/dalvikvm(5712): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
01-05 01:07:53.874: D/dalvikvm(5712): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 152 unimplemented (abstract) methods
01-05 01:07:53.924: D/AndroidRuntime(5712): Calling main entry com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher
01-05 01:07:53.934: D/AndroidRuntime(5712): Shutting down VM
01-05 01:07:53.934: W/dalvikvm(5712): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ffa2a0)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712): uncaught exception
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:95)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:82)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:76)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:237)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.TestCaseCollector.addTestClass(TestCaseCollector.java:83)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.TestCaseCollector.addTestClass(TestCaseCollector.java:71)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.TestCaseCollector.addTestClasses(TestCaseCollector.java:52)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:92)
01-05 01:07:53.939: E/UiAutomatorTestRunner(5712):  ... 6 more
01-05 01:07:53.944: I/AndroidRuntime(5712): VM exiting with result code -1.
```

Comment: How do you run it? Emulator? Version?

Comment: You need to look at the logcat output to understand wher the java.lang.RuntimeException is. Please provide log cat output.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem and have tried all the answers on this page with no luck. I am trying to use the Eclipse export to create the jar file.

Answer (score 3):

**If you get a ClassNotFindException while running your uiautomator tests :**

Some of us my get this error because their ROM puts the folder /data/dalvik-cache in read-only mode. That happened to me with Cyanogen for a S3.

In that case type, in bash :

```
adb shell 
su
chmod 777 /data/dalvik-cache
exit
```

rerun your tests and that should work. As dalvik-cache is locked for apps, uiautomator can't ask dalvik to unzip the jar of your tests and dalvik won't find the its classes.

Answer (score 1):

See if removing the @UiThreadTest annotation or removing the runOnUiThread() call or re-factoring your tests work. But without a logcat, difficult to understand where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Most demos I've seen indicate to install the jar to /data/local/tmp/. I've seen others indicate to try and install it to your sd card (/storage/sdcard0). After doing that it worked. Seems to be a problem with read permissions.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this error by using"ant build" to create my jar.If u use export in eclipse to create a jar file, there might be some errors in the resulting class file, hence the above class not found error.