# How to solve ClassNotFoundException on uiautomator startup?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, gui-testing

I'm trying to create GUI tests for my app with the provided tool(s) from the android-sdk for my app. For the start i've set up a project, as described in http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html in "Configure your development environment". Currently i've taken the example test from http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#sample and put it inside the project UITestsMyAppBasis, in the the package com.MyApp.guitest

the command ant build runs succesfully and i get a jar file in the bin directory of my project. But when i try to start it via:

```
adb push ./UiTestsMyAppBasis.jar /data/local/tmp
adb shell uiautomator runtest UITestsMyAppBasis.jar -c com.MyApp.guitest
```

i get the console output:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.RuntimeException
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=com.MyApp.guitest
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

and the logcat output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.MyApp.guitest
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:98)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:85)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:76)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.MyApp.guitest
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.TestCaseCollector.addTestClass(TestCaseCollector.java:84)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.TestCaseCollector.addTestClass(TestCaseCollector.java:72)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.TestCaseCollector.addTestClasses(TestCaseCollector.java:53)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:95)
```

i'm using an android emulator with

- TargetName: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
- Platform: 4.1.2
- API Level: 16
- CPU/ABI ARM (armeabi-v7a)
- Device: 10.1" WXGA (Tablet) (1280x800;mdpi)
- Memory Options: Ram:512 VM Heap: 32
- Internal Storage: 200 MiB
- SD Card: 256 MiB
- Emulation Options: Use Host GPU

Setting the chmod on /data/dalvik-cache as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13805869/1171328 didn't change the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, this should solve your problem:

-c parameter is used to run the class and not package. so it should be:

`adb shell uiautomator runtest UITestsMyAppBasis.jar -c com.MyApp.guitest.<class_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check this problem is to run this command without using -c # and check if it works. If it works check for the class name that it prints in the terminal is the one that's used with -c

adb shell uiautomator runtest UITestsMyAppBasis.jar